# Making a dictionary using values in a column in pandas Dataframe as keys and having all values in another column as values

Tags: python

Supposes a dataframe:

```
data = {"Column1":["a", "b", "a", "b", "a"], "Column2":["d","e","f", "g", "g"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

  Column1 Column2
0       a       d
1       b       e
2       a       f
3       b       g
4       a       g
```

How do I make a dictionary using values in `Column1` as keys and having all values in `Column2` as values?.

I want to get: `{"a":["d","f","g"], "b":["e","g"]}`

I tried: `dict(zip(df['Column1'], df['Column2']))`

but it gives me only one value per key `{'a': 'g', 'b': 'g'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate lists and convert to dictionary:

```
my_dict = df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].agg(list).to_dict()
```